# I have started my new job but I think I do not like it. What should I do?

Tags: career-development

I have accepted a job offer and started the new job for about 3 months now. I do not enjoy this job as much as I had imagined. The job is fine, not too hard to do, and the time is flexible. However, i still regret my decision of changing my job sometimes. I had this feeling since I started working this new job. But had decided to give it more time to see if i will grow to like this job. Now after 3 months, I think my feeling is still the same. Any advice on should I give it more time? Or 3 months will be enough? The reason I do not like my new job is not really specific, I would say it's a feeling. I just do not feel belonging in this new job which is different from my previous job. Not sure if I describe my feeling correctly here though. Any advice would be much appreciated. Not liking my new job hence not much motivation to do my job actually.

Comment: Do you like being paid? Or are you independently wealthy?

Comment: I strongly disagree with closing this as a duplicate of "How can one resign from a new job gracefully?" The question is rather unclear, so closing as "unclear" would be ok, but OP's issue seems to be whether quitting is the right option, not how to quit gracefully.

Comment: Anyway, the question is not very clear, so maybe it's best to just let it be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people do not work in their dream job, they do it for the money. I suggest that you soldier on and make the best that you can out of it and job hunt for something more suitable.

Really it sounds like an attitude shift would fix most of your issues, I've worked in some absolutely toxic positions quite cheerfully because I brush off the negative stuff. But it doesn't sound like your situation is anywhere near that. Focus on the positives and look around for opportunities. 3 months is not a long time.

Answer (score 2):

First, figure out why you don't like this job. Saying "not really specific" and "it's a feeling" means that you really don't know.

Think about it. Talk about it with friends and former coworkers. Even write yourself notes during the day when you happen upon something that makes you think "*This* isn't good" or "*That* is good".

Without knowing what you like and don't like, you can't make any progress. But learning that, you can determine if this job can become what you want, or if it's a lost cause.

If you decide this job has possibilities, you might be able to alter your behavior or attitude and make it better.

And if you ultimately decide that this isn't the job for you, you'll have a better idea of what to look for in your next job. Find a job that will make you happy for longer than 3 months, give your notice here, then move on.

Answer (score 0):

How far along are you in your career -- that is, is this a more or less entry-level job? If you're still pretty young, I'd recommend trying to stick it out for a year. It doesn't sound like you are terribly unhappy or anything like that (which would change things) -- just that you don't love what you're doing. I would stay with it and do everything you can to make it a worthwhile experience: learn something new, take on different projects that are interesting to you, and try to figure out what it is you like doing (and what appealed to you about your old job that you aren't finding here). You said that it's not very challenging, which may mean it's the perfect opportunity to go above and beyond and challenge yourself. That'll put you in a better position when you're applying for your next job. 
Other than that, it's really a personal decision. No job is worth being deeply unhappy all the time, but the tipping point on the scale between "I've found my life's passion!" and "I can't get out of bed in the morning because I hate my job" is different for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I would give it more time. It is normal to feel a bit out of place as you settle in to a new job, you've left something familiar to start something new, and I remember the same sort of feeling when I started my current role. But I think three months is too short at time to take a decision, and unless the role is really making you unhappy I think you should stick with it for a while and see how you can focus on the positive aspects. Maybe set yourself a decision point at 12 months to see how you feel then.

One last thought: depending on what you do, leaving a job very shortly after starting it may be seen as a negative when applying for new roles.  I interview people regularly, and I wouldn't rule out a candidate who had only spent three months in a role, but I would want to fully understand what had happened and feel that it wouldn't happen again. Leaving quickly can be a perfectly understandable reason, e.g. we had one person leave after a few months because they didn't realize how hard a 90 minute each-way drive to work was and it was impacting their health, but we put a lot of time and money into recruitment and training new hires, and look for people who want a long-term career with us.